# XML file to jpg file

Tags: .net, xml

I'm new in this xml world therefore I have this  xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Graphics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Graphics>
    <PropertiesGraphicsEllipse>
      <Left>56</Left>
      <Top>43.709333795560333</Top>
      <Right>225</Right>
      <Bottom>193.70933379556033</Bottom>
      <LineWidth>1</LineWidth>
      <ObjectColor>
        <A>255</A>
        <R>0</R>
        <G>0</G>
        <B>0</B>
        <ScA>1</ScA>
        <ScR>0</ScR>
        <ScG>0</ScG>
        <ScB>0</ScB>
      </ObjectColor>
    </PropertiesGraphicsEllipse>
    <PropertiesGraphicsLine>
      <Start>
        <X>345</X>
        <Y>21.709333795560333</Y>
      </Start>
      <End>
        <X>371</X>
        <Y>279.70933379556033</Y>
      </End>
      <LineWidth>6</LineWidth>
      <ObjectColor>
        <A>255</A>
        <R>182</R>
        <G>0</G>
        <B>0</B>
        <ScA>1</ScA>
        <ScR>0.4677838</ScR>
        <ScG>0</ScG>
        <ScB>0</ScB>
      </ObjectColor>
    </PropertiesGraphicsLine>
    <PropertiesGraphicsText>
      <Text>Hola Mundo</Text>
      <Left>473</Left>
      <Top>109.70933379556033</Top>
      <Right>649</Right>
      <Bottom>218.70933379556033</Bottom>
      <ObjectColor>
        <A>255</A>
        <R>21</R>
        <G>208</G>
        <B>0</B>
        <ScA>1</ScA>
        <ScR>0.007499032</ScR>
        <ScG>0.630757153</ScG>
        <ScB>0</ScB>
      </ObjectColor>
      <TextFontSize>12</TextFontSize>
      <TextFontFamilyName>Verdana</TextFontFamilyName>
      <TextFontStyle>Normal</TextFontStyle>
      <TextFontWeight>Normal</TextFontWeight>
      <TextFontStretch>Normal</TextFontStretch>
    </PropertiesGraphicsText>
  </Graphics>
</Graphics>
```

I'm trying to take this file and create a new .jpg file from this one using C# VS2008. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is definitely possible to do in C#. These would be the steps that I would suggest:

1. Define a mapping between the graphics primitives (ellipse, line, text, etc) in the XML file and drawing commands in the `System.Drawing` namespace and see whether you find a corresponding method in the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class for each "command" in the XML file.
2. Write code to deserialize the XML document.
3. Draw the primitives.
4. Save to a JPEG image.

The code for drawing would look something like this:

```
// create a bitmap object with a default size
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1024, 768);

// get a graphics object where we are able to draw on
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

// for each PropertiesGraphicsEllipse draw an ellipse
// g.DrawEllipse(...);

// for each PropertiesGraphicsLine draw a line
// g.DrawLine(...);

// for each PropertiesGraphicsText write text
g.DrawString("Hola Mundo", new Font("Verdana", 12), 
    new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 21, 208, 0)), new PointF(473F, 109.7F));

// save as JPEG
bmp.Save(@"C:\tmp\image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thanks 0xA3 I was able to create the jpg file :)